# Button does not want to go right in TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow, gravity

What is wrong with this code? Why doesn't the button go right in this table row?

```
<TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/str1"
                    />
            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/id1"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/id2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="65dp"
                    android:text="@string/str2"
                    android:gravity="right"/>
        </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: It is stuck to the EditText (right side).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should either use **android:stretchColumns="1"** in your TableLayout, so that your EditText pushes your Button to the right.

Or you can use **android:layout_weight** attribute on the views in a tableRow to distribute the space accordingly.

Also, you dont need to specify width and height attributes on the views in a TableRow.

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:stretchColumns="1">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:text="@string/str1"
                />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/id1"
                 />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/id2"
                android:text="@string/str2"
                />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: `android:stretchColumns="1"` was missing. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`android:gravity="right"` is used for the text inside the `Button`. Since it's width is set to `wrap_content`, it has no effect at all.

You need to use `android:layout_gravity` instead. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity

> Standard gravity constant that a child can supply to its parent. Defines how to place the view, both its x- and y-axis, within its parent view group.
>
> Must be one or more (separated by '|') of the following constant values.
>
> (...)
>
> right 0x05    Push object to the right of its container, not changing its size.

Comment: The problem is that I've tried both gravity attibutes and both gave me no result. I think that the lower post is right: I forgot the attribute `stretchColumns`.

Comment: This is what Romanian guy says (it may help to someone): `gravity means "apply gravity to the content of this view" whereas layout_gravity means "apply gravity to this view within its parent." So on a TextView, gravity will align the text within the
bounds of the TextView whereas layout_gravity will align the TextView within the bounds of its parent.`